# How to pass dynamic parameters in requst.httpBody of POST method

Tags: ios, json, web-services, rest, swift3

I was accessing my webservices fine till xcode 7.3 i updated to xcode 8.2 and swift 3, now my app is crashing, here is my code

```
func jsonParsingFromURL () throws {

    let WSLink = "http://XXXXX.co/itXXXXMS/webservice.asmx/GXXXXXX"
    let url = URL(string: WSLink)
    let bodyData = "lastlogindate=\(todayDate)&CompanyId=\(compID)"  //problem is here

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in

        guard let _ = data else { return }
        self.startParsing(data!)
    }
}

func startParsing(_ data :Data) {

    //Am getting error here in this line
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary  
    arrDict.removeAllObjects()

    for i in 0  ..< (dict.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray).count {
        arrDict.add((dict.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray) .object(at: i))
    }
}
```

> json text did not start with array or object and option to allow
>   fragments not set

Actually i found the reason of error but don't know how to fix it.

when i write as,  let bodyData = "lastlogindate=26/11/2016&CompanyId=3" //it is working.

and when i wrap parameters in variables which are dynamic coming from previous viewController like

let date = "26/11/2016", let id = "3" and

let bodyData = "lastlogindate=(date)&CompanyId=(id)" then am getting error.

**So basically my question is how to wrap dynamic variables to request.httpBody in swift 3 ?**

Comment: but till swift 2.2 it was working fine

Comment: yesterday i updated xcode and today its giving this error, do swift 3 changed anything ?

Comment: So what do you suggest ?

Comment: i tested in browser its working

Comment: Try setting `options` in serialization to `.allowFragments`.

Comment: if you look at the actual JSON data being sent back by the remote server (i.e. convert it from Data to a String and then print it out into your console), is it really JSON?

Comment: yes it is JSON, when i write like, let bodyData = "lastlogindate=26/11/2016&CompanyId=3" //it is working. and when i write as, let bodyData = "lastlogindate=(date)&CompanyId=(id)" , then am getting error.

Comment: Maybe you have declared todayDate and compID as Optionals and forgot to unwrap them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in this line while passing parameters to `bodyData`:

```
let bodyData = "lastlogindate=\(todayDate)&CompanyId=\(compID)"

//example lastlogindate = "12/24/2016" and CompanyId = 134
```

When I do `print(bodyData)` I'm getting output as
    "lastlogindate=**optional**(12/24/2016)&CompanyId=**optional**(134)"

Why `optional` was getting added in Swift 3, I dont know.
In Swift 2.2 it was not adding `optional` .

So, what i did is

```
let bodyData = "lastlogindate=" + todayDate + "&CompanyId=" + compID
```

Now,  when I do `print(bodyData)` it gives me correct output as

```
lastlogindate=12/24/2016&CompanyId=134.
```